# How can I optimize this Google App Engine code?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, optimization

I'm relatively new to the Python world, but this seems very straight forward.

Google is yelling at me that this code needs to be optimized:

```
class AddLinks(webapp.RequestHandler):
     def post(self):
          # Hash the textarea input to generate pseudo-unique value
          hash = md5.new(self.request.get('links')).hexdigest()

          # Seperate the input by line
          allLinks = self.request.get('links').splitlines()

          # For each line in the input, add to the database
          for x in allLinks:
               newGroup = LinkGrouping()
               newGroup.reference = hash
               newGroup.link = x
               newGroup.put()

          # testing vs live
          #baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080'
          baseURL = 'http://linkabyss.appspot.com'

          # Build template parameters
          template_values = {
               'all_links': allLinks,
               'base_url': baseURL,
               'reference': hash,
          }

          # Output the template
          path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'addLinks.html')
          self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

The dashboard is telling me that this is using a ton of CPU.

Where should I look for improvements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main overhead here is the multiple individual puts to the datastore. If you can, store the links as a single entity, as Andre suggests. You can always split the links into an array and store it in a ListProperty.

If you do need an entity for each link, try this:

```
# For each line in the input, add to the database
groups = []
for x in allLinks:
     newGroup = LinkGrouping()
     newGroup.reference = hash
     newGroup.link = x
     groups.append(newGroup)
db.put(groups)
```

It will reduce the datastore roundtrips to one, and it's the roundtrips that are really killing your high CPU cap.

Answer (score 3):

Looks pretty tight to me.

I see one thing that may make a small improvement.
Your calling, "self.request.get('links')" twice.

So adding:

```
unsplitlinks = self.request.get('links')
```

And referencing, "unsplitlinks" could help.

Other than that the loop is the only area I see that would be a target for optimization.
Is it possible to prep the data and then add it to the db at once, instead of doing a db add per link?  (I assume the .put() command adds the link to the database)

Answer (score 2):

You can dramatically reduce the interaction between your app and the database by just storing the complete `self.request.get('links')` in a text field in the database.

- only one `put()` per `post(self)`
- the hash isn't stored n-times (for every link, which makes no sense and is really a waste of space)

And you save yourself the parsing of the textfield when someone actually calls the page....

Answer (score 0):

How frequently is this getting called?  This doesn't look that bad... especially after removing the duplicate request.

Answer (score 0):

Can I query against the ListProperty?

Something like

```
SELECT * FROM LinkGrouping WHERE links.contains('http://www.google.com')
```

I have future plans where I would need that functionality.

I'll definitely implement the single db.put() to reduce usage.

Comment: Yes, ListProperties have a cool feature.  If you do LinkGrouping.gql("WHERE links = :1", "http://www.google.com"), it will return all groups that have 'http://www.google.com' in their list.

Answer (score 0):

no/ you can not use something like "links.contains('http://www.google.com')"
GQL not support this